# Multiple parameters in where clause using Slick 2

Tags: sql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

So I've been scouring the documentation, but I couldn't find something as simple as this.

This statement seems to work

```
val row = MyTable.where(_.col1 === "val1").firstOption
```

But this one doesn't

```
val row = MyTable.where(_.col1 === "val1" && _.col2 === "val2").firstOption
```

How can I use multiple parameters in my where clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use underscore for one parameter only once. This is a shortcut for this:

```
val row = MyTable.where(x => x.col1 === "val1").firstOption
```

So in your case this should work:

```
val row = MyTable.where(value => value.col1 === "val1" && value.col2 === "val2").firstOption
```

Comment: `where` is deprecated in slick 2, so now we can use `filter` in place of where, its just basically replacing where with filter, for simple explanation.